# How do I figure out what threads are utilizing a lot of CPU on Wildfly 11 using the CLI tool?

Tags: multithreading, command-line-interface, wildfly, cpu-usage

I'm using Wildfly 11 with Java 8 on Amazon Linux.  How do I use the Wildfly CLI tool to monitor thread usage?  We have high CPU utilization on our app servers and I'm trying to figure out what the problematic theads and operations are.  We do not have "jconsole" installed on our servers or maybe this article would have been helpful -- http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/how-to-monitor-jboss-cpu-usage .

Specifically, I'm wondering what the name of the Wildfly subsystem that I have to type into the CLI tool would be that would reveal the long running/high CPU usage threads.

Comment: You're explicitly mentioning 'threads'. Do you need to identify the processes or the threads inside the processes? Have you already identified the process whose threads cause the high CPU load?

Comment: Yes, using top I have identified the process (the Wildfly application server process) that is gobbling up all the CPU.  I'm not curious about what threads within that are causing this CPU utilization spike.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Java Mission Control and it's flight recording function. You will need to take a copy of jconsole.bat or jconsole.sh and edit to run jmc with the classpath defined. You then use the same custom jmx url as for jconsole

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have Java Mission Control installed and its sadly not an option to install that on our production system.  As such, we'd like to sue the tools we already have.

Comment: Mission Control is part of the JDK,  so you can launch it on your machine and connect to the server

Comment: We only have JRE not JDK installed on the prod servers.  Is MIssion Control also part of JRE?

Comment: You only need the JDK on your local machine

Answer (score 1):

To findout which thread is consuming more CPU you have to collect CPU usage(in RHEL using top command(top -b -n 1 -H -p JBoss_PID)) and thread dump at the same time stamp when you face issue. From the top command output, you can identify process ID's for java threads utilizing a large percentage of the CPU.  For example, output top command shows CPU being used by three Java threads:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  4382 root      25   0 1284m 480m  80m R 39.5 23.7  13:00.64 java
  6657 root      25   0 1284m 480m  80m R 39.5 23.7   7:23.10 java
  16322 root      25   0 1284m 480m  80m R 19.8 23.7  57:51.77 java
```

Using the Thread Dump Analyzer (TDA) tool, you can load the thread dumps that were gathered with the CPU data. Click on the Native-ID column in the upper right pane to sort by native thread ID and cross reference the light weight thread IDs from the top output to see the threads consuming high CPU.

Comment: Wrong: the 'top' output presented here shows only java processes, but not their threads!

Comment: Use top command with correct arguments:  top -b -n 1 -H -p  JBoss_PID

Comment: @Dave no such feature not available with JBoss CLI tool

Comment: use "  jstack -l JBoss_PID >>high-cpu-tdump.out " to capture thread dump